# Trouble with plotly_express scatter's function

Tags: python, plotly

I have a Panda dataframe that looks something like this (snippit of first six rows; formatting is a little bit off):

I have been trying to use this dataframe in plotly express's scatter function.  However, when I use the keyword arguments for range_x and range_y so I can modify the scale, python complains at runtime, saying that

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Does anyone know a good fix for this error?

I've used the example dataframe provided by plotly_express and used plotly_express.scatter(etc.)  It works as intended despite them also editing the range_x and range_y kwargs.

Code that plots the dataframe for me.  result variable is the dataframe.

```py
px.scatter(result, x="SuccEntropy", y="KL-DivergenceFromParent", animation_frame="Age", animation_group="Node",
           size="NodeObs", color="Node", hover_name="Node", 
           size_max=38, range_x=[10, 11], range_y=[0,100])
```

Expected results is a plotted graph while actual results is this error message:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-57a1e6d59efb> in <module>
      1 px.scatter(result, x="SuccEntropy", y="KL-DivergenceFromParent", animation_frame="Age", animation_group="Node",
      2            size="NodeObs", color="Node", hover_name="Node",
----> 3            size_max=38, range_x=[10, 11], range_y=[0,100])

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly_express\_chart_types.py in scatter(data_frame, x, y, color, symbol, size, hover_name, hover_data, text, facet_row, facet_col, error_x, error_x_minus, error_y, error_y_minus, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, color_continuous_scale, range_color, color_continuous_midpoint, symbol_sequence, symbol_map, opacity, size_max, marginal_x, marginal_y, trendline, trendline_color_override, log_x, log_y, range_x, range_y, render_mode, title, template, width, height)
     50     In a scatter plot, each row of `data_frame` is represented by a symbol mark in 2D space.
     51     """
---> 52     return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scatter)
     53 
     54 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly_express\_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
    795     apply_default_cascade(args)
    796     trace_specs, grouped_mappings, sizeref, show_colorbar = infer_config(
--> 797         args, constructor, trace_patch
    798     )
    799     grouper = [x.grouper or one_group for x in grouped_mappings] or [one_group]

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly_express\_core.py in infer_config(args, constructor, trace_patch)
    696     sizeref = 0
    697     if "size" in args and args["size"]:
--> 698         sizeref = args["data_frame"][args["size"]].max() / args["size_max"] ** 2
    699 
    700     if "color" in args:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Error looks to me like its from `size="NodeObs"`. Is "NodeObs" all ints?

Comment: Yes that was the problem!  Thank you.  It turns out all my numbers were somehow strings and not integers/floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that `size="NodeObs"` is not an `int` which throws the error.